# RestClient send IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multipartform-data, restsharp

I am receiving a file from my controller as

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ScanFile(IFormFile request)
```

and how can I pass this in RestSharp as shown below in **AddParameter**. 
I tried setting my own boundary and serialize IFormFile nothing worked out.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api_url/requests");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "bearer API_TOKEN");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"eicar.com\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nX5O!P%@AP[4\\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Did you check this post if it helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799392/sending-http-post-multipart-form-data-field-using-restsharp

Comment: You would need to read the `IFormFile` stream into a byte array. The easiest way to do that is to copy it to a `MemoryStream` and then utilize `ToArray` on that. Then, send the byte array in your request.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

From my console app,

```cs
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:30000/api/Factory");
var request = new RestRequest("UploadDocumentBlob", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json, AlwaysMultipartFormData = true };
request.AddFile("file", Path.Combine(settings.PdfStorePath, "11rwai4q.pdf"));
var uploadDocumentBlobResponse = client.Post<Response>(request).Data;
```

to my api,

```cs
[HttpPost("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<Response> UploadDocumentBlob(IFormFile file)
```

the key thing here is that in `request.AddFile` the first parameter must be `"file"` not any other name.

Hope this helps someone.