# Pass a file to the IFormFile property in the model object and call a API to upload the file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written a Web API function to upload a file and with some other properties, like UserId, Title, and Version. The purpose of this API is to upload a file to the Azure Blob and save the other data to the local database.

Here is the model which the API gets:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("file")]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }     
    
    [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("version")]
    [Required]
    public string Version { get; set; } 
}
```

And here is the API function:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("addDocument")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDocument([FromForm] DocumentModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid document create request.");
    }       
    
    var connectionString = _settings.appConfig.StorageConnectionString;
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    
    var blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(model.UserId);
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();  
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(model.DocumentPath);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        model.File.CopyTo(ms);
        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

        BinaryData uploadData = new BinaryData(fileBytes);
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadData, true);
    }

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Now I have to write a **Console Application in C#** to consume that "file upload API" and pass the model object to that API. Now I don't know how to prepare the model as it has the **"File"** property which is **IFormFile** type.

Can anyone suggest to me how to prepare the above model and pass it to the API with HttpClient class or RestShar library in .net?

I am using .net Core 6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412899/how-to-post-form-data-iformfile-with-httpclient have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it works for me.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var FilePath = @"D:\test.txt";

    formContent.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(FilePath)), "File", Path.GetFileName(FilePath));
    formContent.Add(new StringContent("1"), "UserId");
    formContent.Add(new StringContent("1"), "Title");
    formContent.Add(new StringContent("1"), "Version");
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7233/");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/api/addDocument", formContent);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do it using .net RestSharp library instead of using HttpClient class

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103382/9247039).  this gives the idea how it can be done using restsharp and you have to adapt as per your model.

Answer (score 1):

I have several examples, maybe it will give you an idea how it worsks
https://github.com/managed-code-hub/Storage/blob/main/Samples/WebApiSample/Controllers/StorageController.cs

try passing the IFromFile in the body of the request and for parameters use query string.
and in console app:
[C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)