# Upload image to external API and get the response from POST in JSON in Minimal .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using an external API to host my images on there since this is just a test. The API is a Minimal .NET Core API. I created a class with the properties that the objects will have:

**Item Class**

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace Gyft.Data.Item
{
    public class Item
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In ItemsService Class, I have implemented a method to add an item into the database.

**ItemsService Class**

```
public async Task AddItem(Item item)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=*[KEY_REDACTED]*&image=" + item.Image),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            await _items.InsertOneAsync(item);
        }
```

Now, In **`Program.cs`** file, following POST request is mapped:

```
app.MapPost("/api/items", async (ItemServices itemServices, Item newItem) =>
{
    await itemServices.AddItem(newItem);
});
```

Postman returns a **415 error code**. Am I going about it the right way?

Comment: I intend to somehow get the data from response in JSON so I can get the link of the uploaded image. I will be able to then store that link along with the item's other information in a document.

Comment: your external API expects image in url or inside body ? be sure about it. based on that you might need to read the image before passing on to your external api call.

Comment: @CodingMytra I have been sending image data from the Postman in the "form-data" in "body" of the request. How am I to send it in the form-data?

Comment: are you talking about external api or your api ?

Comment: I am saying that when I send api request to external api to upload the image, i should send it as form data and not as a parameter. I am asking how am I to do that since I am new to this.

Comment: here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798515/9247039) . have a look if this gives you some idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247636/discussion-between-reznov-and-codingmytra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding from form values is not supported in .NET 6. So here is a workaround that you can refer:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ItemServices>();

//other middleware or services....

app.MapPost("/api/items", async ([FromServices]ItemServices itemServices,HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var data = request.Form;
    var newItem = new Item()
    {
        Id = data["Id"],
        Description = data["Description"],
        Title = data["Title"],
        Image = data.Files[0]
    };
    await itemServices.AddItem(newItem);
});
```

Comment: It was something good since I can add the data and is getting read properly while debugging. But I am getting another exception that I have not seen before. I am not sure why it is getting thrown but I'm positive that it is getting thrown by the part where I am actually adding the data to the database.

Comment: Hi @Reznov, I think it should be another question, you need post a new thread and share the database operation code with thrown exception.

Comment: Great. I can post the question and I will share the link with you too if you wanna get in on the action lol