# Uploading an image to a BIM 360 project using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

How do you upload an image to a BIM 360 Project using .NET? I have successfully been able to upload an image to a BIM 360 Project using Postman but when using the same code to perform the same function I get an error message saying:

`"{\"code\":1001,\"message\":\"image has contents that are not what they are reported to be; image_content_type is invalid; \"}"`

The code I used inside of .NET is the following:

```
var client3 = new RestClient("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/" + accountId + "/projects/" + targetProject + "/image");
        var request3 = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
        request3.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request3.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer.access_token);
        request3.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request3.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");            
        request3.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", 
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chunk\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\logo.png\"\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\nimage/png\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
            ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response3 = client3.Execute(request3);
        string updatedProjectImage = response3.Content;
```

Comment: Your image doesn't automatically get added to the request, you have to add it yourself. Looks like you're using RestSharp, check out this question it might answer yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799392/sending-http-post-multipart-form-data-field-using-restsharp or at least get you on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the source [code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/2b68083e7f3de63ef84cd4499ef0ab5d43bbc4fc/src/Autodesk.Forge/Client/ApiClient.cs#L122) here as a reference to create a `PrepareRequest()` function that performs all my requests. The parameters I used to complete the function are as follows:

```
string updatedProjectImage = PrepareRequest(
    "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/" + accountId + "/projects/" + targetProjectId + "/image",
    Method.PATCH,
    new Dictionary<string, string>(),
    null,
    headerParams,
    formParams,
    fileParams,
    new Dictionary<string, string>(),
    "multipart/form-data");
```

headerParams: `"Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer.access_token`

formParams: `"type", "image/png"` (Format can change depending on the image)

fileParams: `"file", fileParam`

fileParam:

```
FileParameter fileParam = FileParameter.Create(
"chunk", 
GetBytesFromFile(fileName), 
Path.GetFileName(fileName), 
"multipart/form-data");`
```

(A reference to how the GetBytesFromFile() function was made can be found in the source code. Lastly fileName includes the full address path).